# Why am I getting "list assignment index out of range" error?

Tags: python, list, nested-loops, nested-lists

I keep getting the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

What's wrong with the following code?

```
myList = [([None] * 8) for x in range(16)]

for i in range(0,7):
    for j in range(0,15):
        myList[i][j] = 2 * i
```

Comment: just remember range(a, b) is actually from a to b-1, not a to b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list comprehension

```
myList = [([None] * 8) for x in range(16)]
```

can be understood like this

```
mylist = []
for x in range(16):
    mylist.append([None] * 8)
```

So, you are creating a list of 16 lists, each contains 8 `None`s. But with the loops

```
for i in range(0,7):
    for j in range(0,15):
```

you are trying to access 15 elements from the first 7 lists. That is why it is failing. Instead, you might want to do

```
for i in range(16):
    for j in range(8):
        ...
```

Actually you can do the same in list comprehension, like this

```
[[2 * i for j in range(8)] for i in range(16)]
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([[2 * i for j in range(8)] for i in range(16)])
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
 [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
 [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
 [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
 [12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16],
 [18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18],
 [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
 [22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22],
 [24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24],
 [26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26],
 [28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28],
 [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]]
```

**Note:** I have used `16` and `8` in the `range` function because it, by default, starts from 0 and iterates till the parameter passed to it - 1. So, 0 to 15 and 0 to 8 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You have your indices reversed; the **outer** list has 16 elements, but you are trying to index the **inner** list past the 8 elements that are there.

That's because your list comprehension built 16 lists of each 8 values, so `len(myList)` is 16, and `len(myList[0])` is 8.

Reverse the ranges:

```
for i in range(15):
    for j in range(7):
        myList[i][j] = 2 * i
```

or reverse the use of `i` and `j` when trying to index against `myList`:

```
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(15):
        myList[j][i] = 2 * i
```

Note that the outer `myList` is using `j` now and each nested inner list is indexed with `i`.

Both `i` and `j` **omit** the last element, if that wasn't intentional, use `8` and `16` rather than `7` and `15`.